# PHPSoap converts a non-repeatable field into an array in case of multiple occurence

Tags: php, soap

I've defined a SOAP webservice with an xsd type defining a non-repeatable field.

If I provide many occurrences of this field, I expect PHPSoap to throw an Exception or something wrong, but it converts it into an array (as expected if repetition was allowed).

Here is an extract of XSD part of the WSDL :

```
<xsd:complexType name="OrderItem">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="orderId" maxOccurs="1"/> <!-- maxOccurs is useless as default value is 1 but to be suremore than ... -->
        <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="sku"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

If I send this request message, I got an array behind the SOAP layer (I expected an Exception) :

```
<OrderItem>
    <orderId>12345685</orderId>
    <sku>SKU123456</sku>
    <orderId>12345686</orderId>
</OrderItem>
```

Here is a var_dump of the OrderItem object received :

```
OrderItem::__set_state(array(
  'orderId' => 
    array (
      0 => '12345685',
      1 => '12345686',
   ),
  'sku' => 'SKU123456',
```

)

Is this normal ?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've messed with soap but my gut is that you need to set a type on the element definition so that it can't force it to an array. maxOccurs will only make sure you have a single orderId. Converting multiple elements into a single array is still valid.

Comment: In this case I want orderId to be non-repeatable but if i send a message with multiple orderId, it converts it into an array "instead of" throwing an Exception or any parsing error (as it shouln't accept it).

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. You already have it set to string and it's still converting it to an array. That's very odd behavior. I'll see if I can find a solution.